# jquery :not selection is not excluding expected element

Tags: jquery

Given the following:

```js
// all text should be red except in the excludeme id
$('body:not(#excludeme)').css('color', 'red');
// $('#excludeme').css('color','blue');
```

```css
body {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
 div text
</div>
<br />
<span>
 <a id="excludeme">this text should be green</a>
 <br />
 span text
</span>
```

All text appears red, but the text in the excludeme id should remain green.
Why does the :not selector not exclude the selected id?

Comment: The link will inherit the color from body as you can see if you inspect the element. The color-css attribute won't be appended to the link itself.

Comment: You should work the other way around: make the body red and `#excludeme` green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:not` is working as expected. If you inspect html code you can see that `a` element does not have inline style that changes color to red. It is getting color from parent element because all other elements have red color. If you want you can declare a style for a element like this in `css`

```
#excludeme{
    color: green;
}
```

You can read more about `inheritance` in `css` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `:not()` then the color will be inherited from the `parent` element.

Try below code -

```js
// all text should be red except in the excludeme id
$("#excludeme").css('color', 'green')
$('body').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div>
        div text
    </div>
    <br />
    <span>
        <a id="excludeme">this text should be green</a>
        <br />
        span text
    </span>
</body>
```

Or you can also try this-

```css
body{
  color: red;
}

#excludeme{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        div text
    </div>
    <br />
    <span>
        <a id="excludeme">this text should be green</a>
        <br />
        span text
    </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inherited from body, since body also has no `excludeme` id, see:

```js
// all text should be red except in the excludeme id
$('body:not(#excludeme)').css('color', 'red');
//$('#excludeme').css('color','blue');
```

```css
body {
  color: green;
}
#excludeme {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    div text
  </div>
  <br>
  <span>
<a id="excludeme">this text should be green</a>
<br>
span text
</span>
</body>
a
```

If you explicitly specify the color for `excludeme` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As @TiiJ7 suggests, Check this if it suits, [Click Me!!](https://jsfiddle.net/ojwkaLgx/)

Change CSS by this:

```
body {
  color: red;
}
```

And JS by this:

```
$('#excludeme').css('color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is selecting any body element that doesn't have an id of `excludeme`. That just selects the body element of the document. You then apply the style to that element which overrides the style you applied in your CSS.

You end up with something like this where the `#excludeme` element is not targeted in any way:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="color: red">
        ...
        <a id="excludeme">this text should be green</a>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to directly target that element to override the style.